# Javascript code cant be run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck with this javascript code. I want to add a new row to the table and then be able to remove it. I just can't find my mistake.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
$('.Add').click(function()
{
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    row.find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
    $('input[type="button"]',    row).removeClass('Add').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
});

$('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function()
{
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Process:</td>
        <td>People required:</td>
        <td>Add/Remove Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="process">
                <option value="1">BLD</option>
                <option value="2">KEY</option>
                <option value="3">ART</option>
                <option value="4">BG</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type='text' ></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='Add' value='Add new item'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you include `jQuery` to your script?

Comment: See what error you have in console

Comment: working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1956/

Comment: @KhorneHoly yes I did

Comment: @Riad exactly, I also tried to run it there. Its working, but its not working in my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jQuery, but missing the jQuery reference.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add your jQuery code on [DOM ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

**Working code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.Add').click(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
        row.find('input').val('');
        $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
        $('input[type="button"]', row).removeClass('Add').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
      });

      $('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Process:</td>
      <td>People required:</td>
      <td>Add/Remove Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="process">
          <option value="1">BLD</option>
          <option value="2">KEY</option>
          <option value="3">ART</option>
          <option value="4">BG</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='button' class='Add' value='Add new item'>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. wrap your code inside a `document.ready` function
2. also include jQuery library

Code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Add').click(function()
    {

        var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
        row.find('input').val('');
        $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
        $('input[type="button"]',    row).removeClass('Add').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
    });

    $('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function()
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    });
```

or put your `script` code just before the end of the `body tag`

You need to wait for the `elements` to be available the `dom` on page load before binding event handlers.

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Process:</td>
        <td>People required:</td>
        <td>Add/Remove Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="process">
                <option value="1">BLD</option>
                <option value="2">KEY</option>
                <option value="3">ART</option>
                <option value="4">BG</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type='text' ></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='Add' value='Add new item'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>

$('.Add').click(function()
{

    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    row.find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
    $('input[type="button"]',    row).removeClass('Add').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
});

$('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function()
{
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CDN/js file of Jquery as your are using `$` in the script this will solve your problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
// ------CDN of jquery
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.Add').click(function()
{
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    row.find('input').val('');
    $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
    $('input[type="button"]',    row).removeClass('Add').addClass('RemoveRow').val('Remove item');
});

$('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function()
{
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Process:</td>
        <td>People required:</td>
        <td>Add/Remove Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="process">
                <option value="1">BLD</option>
                <option value="2">KEY</option>
                <option value="3">ART</option>
                <option value="4">BG</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type='text' ></td>
        <td><input type='button' class='Add' value='Add new item'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also view the code in jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/vsvvssrao/62yr8tav/